# Count the number of dates in a single cell

Tags: excel, date, text, countif

I need to be able to count the number of dates in a single Excel cell that is formatted as text. The dates do not follow a specific format. Here is an example of the text in a single cell:

> "John was born on 11/15/2005. Tim was born on 1/2/02. Jeff was born on 05/5/13."

The formula should return a count of 3 dates for this cell. I've tried COUNTIF, search with wild cards. the best I can do is to get a count of one for the first instance discovered using:

```
=COUNTIF(F3,"*/*/*")
```

Comment: Assuming that you do not have any errant `/` in the string you can use this: `=(LEN(F3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F3,"/","")))/2`

Comment: I do have text like "E/O" that throws off counting. Instead of using a specific text like "/", could I do a format search like "*/*/*" and then substitute "" ?

Comment: The problem is search returns the first instance.  Also in a string like `E/O John was born on 11/15/2005.` it would find `/O John was born on 11/` which satisfies the search parameters of "/*/".  The only way I know is a UDF but that is vba.  Though there may be others that can come up with a better solution.  One question, does the Errant `/` happen more than once per string? Because `=QUOTIENT(LEN(F3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F3,"/","")))/2)` would allow for the errant one, but not 2 or more.

Comment: Yes the Errant "/" can occur more than once... thanks for your guidance!

Comment: `=(LEN(K13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K13,"/",""))-SUM(LEN(K13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K13,{"E/O","S/U"},"")))/LEN({"E/O","S/U"}))/2`.  You would need to know ALL the possible substrings that have `/`.  In this example it is `E/O` and `S/U` and in both `{ }` areas in the formula put that list.  This is as close as I can get you without vba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are so many potential patterns, I would recommend a User Defined Function (UDF) written using VBA.  One could use a Regular Expression to define the data.  The complexity of the regular expression depends on the potential variability in the date string.  The example below tests for any `/` separated string that has one or two digits in the first and second sections, and two or four digits in the third section.  But the pattern could be much more complex.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=CountDates(cell_ref)
```

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function CountDates(S As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\b(?:\d{1,2}/){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b"
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    Set MC = .Execute(S)
    CountDates = MC.Count
End With
End Function
```

Comment: One of these days Microsoft is going to pull its head out and give us regex functions. I am sure they have had thousands submitted. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm not holding my breath.  But at least it can be easily implemented in VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've voted for this functionality at https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9022339-built-in-regex-regular-expressions-functions-to

Comment: @brettdj Thanks.  I'll take a look there.

Comment: I will go the VBA route... thank you all for your quick and thorough responses!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Scott Craner's first suggestion, copy say A1 into B1 and C1, in D1:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(B1))/4+(LEN(A1)-LEN(C1))/3
```

Then select ColumnB, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Replace..., Find what: `/??/`, Replace All. Then repeat for ColumnC but with `/?/`.